# Sinon Ember view test, cannot access controller in view

Tags: unit-testing, view, ember.js, sinon

I am trying to test this code in a view:

```
attributeBindings: ['style'] #tested ok

style: (->
    if @get('controller.isFilterApplied')
      'display: block;'
    else
      'display: none;'
  ).property('controller.isFilterApplied')
```

In test file using sinon and qunit and the test for attributeBindings works well, so I assume the connections of the file are built:

```
test 'attributeBindings', ->
  deepEqual @view.get('attributeBindings'),
    ['style'],
    'attributeBindings match'
```

Next, I try to test the `style` function as above,

I tried `this.view.get('controller')` in my test file, but it returned null even if I added all the controllers in the test file

```
needs: [
    #all controllers related are added here
  ]
```

I tried a not-good way to do it:

```
test 'style -isFilterApplied false', ->
  originalGet = @view.get
  getStub = sinon.stub(@view, 'get')
  getStub.withArgs('controller.isFilterApplied').returns(false)
  @view.get = originalGet
  equal @view.get('style'), 'display: none;', 'style on true'
```

but the returns false property did not work and `@get 'controller.isFilterApplied'` returned null when I debugged it.

So, how could I manually set the controller of the view to the controller it should be linked to in my test file please? Or how should I change the sinon

Answer (score 0):

```
moduleFor 'view:viewName', 'viewName',
  setup: ->
    @view.set 'controller', App.__container__.lookup('controller:theControllerINeed')
```

I added this to setup function, and then this.view.controller is defined now.